# CoreData: how to populate array (getting by parse XML components ) and save them using CoreData, in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, xml-parsing, nsmanagedobjectcontext

**One project that I was trying to do was developing an XML parser to parse XML components and save them using CoreData, as well as showing them through TableView.**

*already I did parse the data from xml file. and Saved the parsed data in to 3 arrays.*

Now I need to store this data in to the core-data.

```
how s'd i populate these 3 arrays in to core-data?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's docs are well worth a read when starting to use Core Data. You can find the starting out guide here: [Core Data Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html)